# Turn clipped image with css

Tags: css, image, animation, rotation

Apologies if my question has been asked but I am seeking to rotate and image that has been clipped down to a size selected by user. For examples purpose lets say they can choose 2cm x 2 cm or 4cm x 4cm. And then I use css clipping to get correct size. My colleage give show me this but now he is gone for vacation.

```
.avatar {
  clip-path: inset(20px 20px 20px 20px);
}
```

Now I wish to allow a something fancier with a image turned for the profile avatar like rotate so image is clipped like diamond for instance.

[image]

Is this what transform css is for? I see transform, animate, rotate and am not good with css. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you want to use `transform: rotate();` or similar here because the image will get tipped on its side. I would stick with `clip-path` but use `polygon` instead of `inset`.

```css
.avatar {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
}
```

```html
<img class="avatar" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
```

Here is a demo of the issue using `clip-path: inset()` and `transform: rotate()`;

```css
.avatar {
  clip-path: inset( 20px );
  transform: rotate( -45deg );
}
```

```html
<img class="avatar" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate the element you can use transform

```
transform: rotate(45deg)
```

if you want this to be an animation, you need to set rotate 0 before, something like this:

```
div {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: .2s;
}

div:hover {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: it'd be `45deg`